# Are there no further developments in GnuPG?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

Though the GnuPG website shows the last stable release date to be: 2010-10-18, I feel there are no major improvements. Till the year 2003-2004, I used to see active developments and releases.

I downloaded both, GnuPG and Cryptophane, but there is no option to create a 4096-bit key. Also, the Diffie-Hellman algorithm is missing.

Comment: Probably should ask on their site/forums/mailing list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see what GnuPG is doing, have a look at this 2010-09-20 announcement :

[The last 9 months of GnuPG development](http://marc.info/?l=gnupg-devel&m=128497898424163&w=3).

Comment: good show sir +1